# Using Function Interface in method for generic return type with single line

Tags: java-8

I have this code:

```
public class FunctionTest {

    public Double getDouble(Function<Integer, Double> function) {
        function = t -> Double.valueOf(t);
        return function.apply(???); //not sure how to implement this
    }

    public Function<Integer, Double> getFunction(Integer t) {
        return r -> Double.valueOf(t); // not able to fetch value from this as the return type is Function
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Function<Integer, Double> f = t -> Double.valueOf(t); // works fine
        System.out.println(f.apply(4)); // how to aechive this using method?
        System.out.println(f);
    }

}
```

If you see `t -> Double.valueOf(t)` works fine with the combination `f.apply(4)` now the question is how to design a method for same I tried two method but failed.

Please assist me in this.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I just figured out how to do this, was simple but not sure, if it is effective

```
public Function<Integer, Double> getFunction() {
        return r -> Double.valueOf(r);
    }
```

and then

```
object.getFunction().apply(integer)
```

Comment: you can simplify your `getFunction()` to `return Double::valueOf`